# How to split title into multiple lines in matlab plots

Tags: matlab, plot, split, title

I have multiple images displaying in matlab plot along with titles as textual descriptions. 
Some of the titles are long and are overlapping with adjacent images. So, how could i automatically adjust the titles by splitting them into multiple lines.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use a cell array of strings as input:

```
title({'hello','world'})
```

each will show on a separate line.

Comment: you can use a function like [this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/9909-line-wrap-a-string) to help you automatically wrap long lines at specified max number of char per line.

Comment: Thanks you @amro. However, I want to automatically adjust the number of lines to any title (can be a long sentence).

Comment: @vidyadhar: see the function I just linked to :)

Comment: yeah just tried it. That suits for me now. Thanks :)